# How to use nx affected for multiple targets with different args for each?

Tags: nrwl-nx, nrwl

In our project we use an nx monorepos for multiples angular apps.
I tried this command :

`nx affected -t lint build test --base=origin/master --head=HEAD --parallel=3 --runInBand --logHeapUsage --parallel=3 --code-coverage`

But I had the error :
[image]

I would to use nx affected to run multiples targets with specifics args for each.
I didn't find in the document the way to do it.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do a "one liner". So I'd run 3 affected commands, one for each target. For example the Nx Cloud CI github action script splits these commands into separate agents https://nx.dev/recipes/ci/monorepo-ci-github-actions#distributed-ci-with-nx-cloud